# Should i use isset() with ctype_*?

Tags: php

Is it better if I type:

```
if (ctype_alnum($x)) echo true;
```

instead of

```
if (isset($x) && ctype_alnum($x)) echo true;
```

?

---

I understand that `ctype_*` finds `NULL` and empty string values as `false`, and it doesn't give an Error message if `$x` doesn't exist, but does that mean I shouldn't use `isset()` with it?

Or do i just use `isset()` just in case future *PHP* updates changed how `ctype_*` treats `NULL` and empty string values?

Comment: When you say `Empty` do you mean an undefined variable or an empty string (`''`)?

Comment: @JamesFenwick `''` without space inside,

Comment: Why not use `!empty($x)`? It will not complain about not existing variable

Comment: @Justinas I would use it, But what i was surprised that i didn't get any `Notice` from `ctype_*` when the variable didn't exist, And from @James Fenwick answer, It actually appears When i set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `$x` is undefined and notices are on, it will throw a notice that `$x` is undefined. And even if they are off, a good practice is to check it before using it.

```
<?php
   echo ctype_alnum($x);
?>
```

result:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: x in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
```

Comment: academic question: which is more efficient; swallowing a `notice` or checking `isset()`?

Comment: checking `isset()` ... setting PHP to not to display "errors" doesn't mean it doesn't process them

Answer (score 1):

```php
ctype_alnum(null);
// false
ctype_alnum('');
// false
ctype_alnum($x);
// Notice:  Undefined variable: x [...]
```

You are correct when you say that `ctype_*` finds `null` and empty strings false but as @Flash Tunder points out it will raise a notice.

You should know if the variable you are testing exists, and if you don't already know that you should check with `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

well it is surely better to check that `$x` is set...  but, there is a debate on which is worse on performance, `isset()` or producing a `notice`.

I would likely use `isset($x)` and check but:

```
... 
if (@ctype_alnum($x)) echo true;
...
```

using the `@` to suppress the error, may be best.

**EDIT:** according to this [link](http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance)

> The difference was that suppressing the notice (a notice!) took 100% as long as just checking if it existed first.

so...   `isset($x)` it is.

Comment: If you're talking performance, using `@` is likely to be the *worst* possible approach. It has a tendency to prevent the compiler from making various optimisations because it effectively brackets your code with `$temp = error_reporting(0);` and `error_reporting($temp);`

Comment: I actually just found that out and edited my answer.  (y)